# PHP calendar recurrence logic

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar, recurrence

I know that there are a million projects out there that have done this already. Having said that what I am trying to do is create an online calendar using PHP & MySQL here is what I am planning:

1. tables in database

   ```
   ((calendar_item)
   id, title, start_date, start time, end time, recurrence_type_id,
   recurrence_qty, interval, end_date)
   ((recurrence_type)
   id, name, value (where I want to store the logic so it can be edited
   on the fly))
   ((calendar_item_exception)
   id, calendar_item_id, title, start_date, start time, end time,
   recurrence_type_id, recurrence_qty, interval, end_date)
   ((join_calendar_day)
   calendar_id, day_id)
   ((day)
   id, name)
   ```
2. Basic flow, pull all records from the database INNER JOIN calendar_item and calendar_item_exception ON id/calendar_item_id
3. begin by looking at today's date for an exception and print anything that's there... if nothing move on to the calendar_item.

This all makes perfect sense in my head up until this point. I'd like to know where to go from here to add the actual logic for the recurrence_id and how to implement it:

ie item is on __date recurs (recurrence_id) daily (qty) 5x (interval) every 3 days (join_calendar_day) on Monday, Wednesday, Friday

I have seen the ical format, and have looked at PEAR, but honestly can't grasp the next step in my head to make the exceptions (which I really want to see happen without using another framework, preferably just PHP and MySQL).

To clarify my question further, I am looking for real world examples, not abstract principles; I am not programmer, so I have to see something working so I can dissect it to understand it.

No PEAR, no Ruby, no Horde, no other frameworks, just PHP and MySQL and as simple as possible please.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of these questions:

- [Design question: How would you design a recurring event system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123793/design-question-how-would-you-design-a-recurring-event-system)
- [What’s the best way to model recurring events in a calendar application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85699/whats-the-best-way-to-model-recurring-events-in-a-calendar-application)

A good link from one of those questions is [this article](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) about it by Martin Fowler.

Comment: I looked through those posts and they did not answer my specific question which is why I asked this. I also read through the pdf, I am looking for specific examples using real data in php in a way I can understand it, not abstract expressions... 

yes I am ADD And need help [;o)

Comment: On a side note, I realize that this question has been answered a million times, but the answer always involves some abstract principle,  or use of a "Framework" of some kind, which does NOT answer MY question. I have looked for this answer for 6mos to no avail

Comment: @Tim have you found a solution for this? I'm looking for something very similar