# Parse.com to create calendar

Tags: ios, parse-platform, calendar, pfobject

Up to this point in my apps, I have used localendar.com or Google calendar to display calendars of events for churches.  This works out great, but requires them to add events either from a different app, or from a computer.

I am considering using Parse.com, and setting up a class for a Calendar.  I know I can set a date column and then using

```
[query whereKey:@"myDateCol" greaterThan:[NSDate date]];
```

have it show just the PFObjects that are in the future.

My concern is with regards to two areas: size of class, and repeating events.  If I go about it the way of each row of the class being an event, with one specific date in the date column, how could I determine a repeat event?  I could always set a `BOOL` value in the class and if YES, have the app perform some code to add in more dates, but this would only work if repeating indefinitely for an extended period of time.

What would be your suggestions for creating a calendar with Parse.com's servers, that allowed for repeat events, and didn't require a constantly increasing file size?

Comment: I would look into a structure as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85699/whats-the-best-way-to-model-recurring-events-in-a-calendar-application. Gist of it is two classes: one for individual events and another for repeating events with a link structure between them

Comment: @Russell Don't really think I can do that with Parse and iOS

Comment: Sure you can. You'll have two Parse classes, let's call them `Event` and `RecurringEvent`. The `RecurringEvent` class will have a one-to-many relationship with `Event`, which is the link structure mentioned before. Check out the Parse relationship docs for more details

Comment: Ok, wow, really not following that at all.

Comment: StackOverflow is really meant for answerable code-level questions so this may be better suited for the Parse Developers Forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers). Try checking it out if you have questions after reading through the documentation on relationships

Comment: I'd love to do that, but no one ever responds to anything on Parse forums.

Comment: People do respond but it will take more time than simple code questions here. The developers forum certainly has fewer people following it, but consider that you're not exactly asking a quick and easy question by requesting for help architecting your app.